# Backup Android SQLite database on Windows Azure Cloud

Tags: android, sqlite, azure

I'm trying to find a way to backup Sqlite database from my android app to a cloud Windows Azure. I have just implemented the method that copy the sqlite database in a folder of external sd card, now I would backup this file to a cloud.

I have seen this official guide: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/

but I don't understand if it is possible. Have you a guide or a faq?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to send your file to Azure blob storage: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/

There's an Android SDK available: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android/